# React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components). The webpage is blank when ContextProvider is used in Index.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, jwt

I am working on a react website, where I am trying to use AuthTokens to create persistent login. The moment I wrap my AuthCotextProvider in Index.js I get the following error and the webpage is just blank.

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Here are my Code Snippets of App.js and Index.js

Index.js

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";

import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthContextProvider} from '../src/store/auth-context.js';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

// const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
// const container = document.getElementById('root');
// // Create a root.
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  
  <AuthContextProvider>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
     </BrowserRouter>
     </AuthContextProvider>
  
);
```

App.js

```js
import React,{useContext} from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import {Redirect} from "react-router-dom";
import Layout from "./components/Layout.js";
import Navigation from "./components/navigation.jsx";
import Reports from "./components/Reports";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Signup from "./components/Signup.jsx";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard";
import Forms from "./components/Forms";
import FormsProceed from "./components/FormsProceed";
import AuthContext from "./store/auth-context.js";

export default function App() {

  const authCtx = useContext(AuthContext);

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/' exact>
          <Home />
        </Route>
        {!authCtx.isLoggedIn && (
          <Route path='/login'>
            <Login />
          </Route>
        )}
        {!authCtx.isLoggedIn && (
          <Route path='/signup'>
            <Signup />
          </Route>
        )}
        {!authCtx.isLoggedIn && (
          <Route path='/signup'>
            <Signup />
          </Route>
        )}
        {!authCtx.isLoggedIn && (
          <Route path='/dashboard'>
            <Dashboard />
          </Route>
        )}
        {!authCtx.isLoggedIn && (
          <Route path='/forms'>
            <Forms />
          </Route>
        )}
        {!authCtx.isLoggedIn && (
          <Route path='/formproceed'>
            <FormsProceed />
          </Route>
        )}
        {!authCtx.isLoggedIn && (
          <Route path='/reports'>
            <Reports />
          </Route>
        )}
        <Route path='*'>
          <Redirect to='/' />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Layout>
  );
```

I am also attaching the inspect element error image for better understanding.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBdMJ.png)

Added the code snipper for auth-context:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';

let logoutTimer;

const AuthContext = React.createContext({
  token: '',
  isLoggedIn: false,
  login: (token) => {},
  logout: () => {},
});

// const calculateRemainingTime = (expirationTime) => {
//   const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
//   const adjExpirationTime = new Date(expirationTime).getTime();

//   const remainingDuration = adjExpirationTime - currentTime;

//   return remainingDuration;
// };

const retrieveStoredToken = () => {
  const storedToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
//   const storedExpirationDate = localStorage.getItem('expirationTime');

//   const remainingTime = calculateRemainingTime(storedExpirationDate);

//   if (remainingTime <= 3600) {
//     localStorage.removeItem('token');
//     localStorage.removeItem('expirationTime');
//     return null;
//   }

  return {
    token: storedToken,
    // duration: remainingTime,
  };
};

export const AuthContextProvider = (props) => {
  const tokenData = retrieveStoredToken();
  
  let initialToken;
  if (tokenData) {
    initialToken = tokenData.token;
  }

  const [token, setToken] = useState(initialToken);

  const userIsLoggedIn = !!token;

  const logoutHandler = useCallback(() => {
    setToken(null);
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    // localStorage.removeItem('expirationTime');

    if (logoutTimer) {
      clearTimeout(logoutTimer);
    }
  }, []);

  const loginHandler = (token, expirationTime) => {
    setToken(token);
    localStorage.setItem('token', token);
    // localStorage.setItem('expirationTime', expirationTime);

    // const remainingTime = calculateRemainingTime(expirationTime);

    // logoutTimer = setTimeout(logoutHandler, remainingTime);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (tokenData) {
      console.log(tokenData.duration);
      logoutTimer = setTimeout(logoutHandler, tokenData.duration);
    }
  }, [tokenData, logoutHandler]);

  const contextValue = {
    token: token,
    isLoggedIn: userIsLoggedIn,
    login: loginHandler,
    logout: logoutHandler,
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {props.children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AuthContext;
```

Can someone Suggest how to solve the error and get the website running?

Comment: Can you check AuthContextProvider  is being exported from auth-context.js? Looks to me like a missing export in that file

Comment: Yes It is being exported.
This is what I have.
"""export const AuthContextProvider = (props) => {
  const tokenData = retrieveStoredToken();"""

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this we can't figure out if there is something wrong in your provider component or not. But one thing I suspect is that you might be using new `v6` of `react-router-dom` (https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview) package and if yes then your code needs to be re-structured as per new API of `react-router-dom` and that might solve the problem.

Comment: I have added the code snippet for auth-context. I have exported everything right. I am still not sure of the issue.  I am using 5.2.0 for react-router-dom.